# How to pass data from functional component to class component in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I want to pass data from my App.js file to a sub class component.I have tried with props,but its not workng at all

```
const org = 'Organization Dashboard'
const remotes = 'FromAdmin';
const DashboardContainer = ()=>(
  <Sidebar org={org}>
  <div className="App">
    <Route path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard}/> 
    <Route path='/mytab' component={MyTab}/>
    <Route path='/team' component={MyTeam}/>
    <Route path='/settings' component={Settings}/>
    <Route path='/logout' component={Logout}/>
    <Route path='/team-settings/:param1' component={TeamSettings}/>
    **<Route remotes='remotes' path='/user-settings/:param1'   component={MyTab}/>**
  </div>
  </Sidebar>
)
```

I want to pass data in MyTab class component, when i use this.props in myTab , its showing undefined

Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're trying to pass `remotes='remotes'` to `MyTab`. Components rendered by a `Route` are passed only the [route props](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props), but you can use an anonymous inner function to slip in extra props. *Don't forget to pass on the route props if you need them!*

```
<Route
  path='/user-settings/:param1'
  component={routeProps => <MyTab {...routeProps} remotes='remotes' />}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the **component**. By default, component accepts a class-based or function-based component. But you can **override** the **component**. Not only data you can pass **functions** as well. But you should not do this. Use **redux** to achieve this kind of thing. If it is **static** data then you can pass this way. But id it is **dynamic data** then use **redux** instead.

```js
<Route
    path = '/myTab'
    component = {(props) => <MyTab {...props} data={data}/>}
/>
```